# Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE replacing ; delimited strings with quoted strings

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I need a simple replace function which replaces a semicolon delimited list of strings to quoted comma delimited strings.

'123;Asd;_P1;' replaces to '123', 'Asd', '_P1'

Tried this but the last string missed the quotes and also string can have other chars.

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('123;234;345;123','([[:alnum:]]+);', '''\1'',') List  FROM DUAL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `regexp_replace` here, a simple `replace` should be sufficient.  It appears that you just want to replace a semicolon with the string "', '" and then add a single quote before and after the string.

```
select q'{'}' ||
       replace( '123;234;345;123', ';', q'{','}' ) ||
       q'{'}'
  from dual
```

Comment: I am not able to make it work in WHERE clause. `WHERE Col1 IN (q'{'}' || replace('MK2.3;P002;0001112', ';',q'{','}') || q'{'}'))` Can you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: @AnitaKulkarni - That's because you've asked the wrong question.  You can't use string transforms to change a single delimited string into a set of strings in a `WHERE` clause.  You can parse a delimited string to populate a collection and use that collection in your query https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( REGEXP_REPLACE('123;234;345;123','([[:alnum:]]+);', '''\1'','), ',([[:alnum:]]+)', ',''\1''')   FROM DUAL;`

Comment: what if the fields contain chars other than alphanumerics? ('_P1' for example)